# Netgear A7000 on Ubuntu 16.04 not working

Tags: networking

output from *lsusb*:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0846:9054 NetGear, Inc.
```

and from *iwconfig*:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s25   no wireless extensions.
```

Im new to linux and currently tethering connection from my windows desktop any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest that you get a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tether or whatever means possible. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8814au 
sudo dkms build -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21
sudo dkms install -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21
```

Reboot with the device inserted and your wireless should be working.

Comment: This also works on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Followed these but `iwconfg` still does not list the device when I plug it in.

Comment: @Peter I suggest that you start your own new question.

Comment: I did: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222871/cannot-install-a7000-network-adapter-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer above for 18.04 as well.  Had to create an account for GitHub first. 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au.git ( will ask for username and password)
sudo dkms add ./rtl8814au 
sudo dkms build -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21
sudo dkms install -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21

Answer (score -1):

That solution didn't work for me. But after the installation of realtek 802.11ac driver netgear A7000 works fine now. (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS)

The steps are [on this blog post](https://blog.abysm.org/2020/03/realtek-802-11ac-usb-wi-fi-linux-driver-installation/)

The driver is from [this Kali Linux repository](https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/contrib/r/realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms/)

Simply download the latest `.deb` package for the driver from there, and install using a command like this (depending on the version you download) in the same directory as the downloaded file: `sudo apt install ./realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms_5.6.4.2~git20200916-0kali1_all.deb` (tip: type `realtek` and then press tab to get the full name!).