# Can't connect to the internet via Netgear A7000 adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, adapter, netgear

I've been trying to connect to the internet via my adapter all day, the only way I'm able to post this is via USB tethering.

Earlier, I noticed I wasn't able to connect to the internet on this computer. I thought I'd just redo what I did when I first set up this computer which worked really well: [Netgear A7000 on Ubuntu 16.04 not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025695/netgear-a7000-on-ubuntu-16-04-not-working) - though I tried that twice and it didn't work, so I'm stuck on here looking for outdated answers from questions from 2015.

I used lsusb, and this is what shows up: https://pastebin.com/JuyCqaNB

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What part of the process didn't work? Did any step throw an  error? Is there any clue after this terminal command? `sudo modprobe 8814au` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response: when I use sudo modprobe 8814au, it says - modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8814au': Exec format error

Comment: We wonder if the last dkms build went correctly. Please see if there are any clues in the log. What does this tell us? `cat /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814au/4.3.21/4.15.0-34-generic/x86_64/log/make.log` Please confirm that you are using the kernel version in my command: `uname -r` If not -34, substitute your kernel version in the command above for 4.15.0-34-generic.

Comment: To the first command : https://pastebin.com/TTLzeUPb

Comment: When I entered uname -r, it responded with: 4.15.0-34-generic

Comment: Even though you are running -34, it built against -29. Wierd. Studying...

Comment: Please show us: `cd rtl8814au && modinfo 8814au.ko | grep ver` We believe it will *not* show the matching kernel version: "vermagic:       4.15.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload"

Comment: All it said is: bash: cd: rtl8814au: No such file or directory

Comment: Where did you git clone the driver file? You need to cd (change directories) into that location.

Comment: I believe it's cloned into the home folder, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Oh, I'm stupid and kept cd'ing into the rtl file, so now I'm getting - modinfo: ERROR: Module 8814au.ko not found.

Comment: I will prose to temporarily fix the wireless while I study how to fix the error in the 'make' log. Please see my answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to remove the dkms installation:

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8814au/4.3.21 --all
```

Confirm that it is no longer present:

```
sudo dkms status
```

You should see no 8814au entries. If so, proceed.

Next, find where you cloned the driver files:

```
sudo updatedb
locate rtl8814au
```

You want the one in your /home/[user] directory; /home/ubuntuisscary for example. Change to that directory using the bash shorthand for '/home/ubuntuisscary', or whatever your user directory is named:

```
cd ~/rtl8814au
```

If you find that the file is in Downloads, then:

```
cd ~/Downloads/rtl8814au
```

Now we build the file for your current kernel.

```
make clean
git pull
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8814au
```

Any improvement?

**EDIT**: When Update Manager installs a newer kernel version, also known as linux-image, after the requested reboot, recompile:

```
cd ~/rtl8814au
make clean
git pull
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8814au
```

Comment: Pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/xTWiJenP

Comment: Testing it now.

Comment: Ooops! I will edit in a moment; it is, obviously `sudo modprobe 8814au` It is late here!!

Comment: Oh, lol! I'll try that and restart now

Comment: Alright - I'm now getting an error that states | modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8814au': Exec format error

Comment: Please show: `modinfo 8814au | grep vermagic`

Comment: vermagic:       4.15.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload

Comment: It appears that only the dkms is installed. I will edit in a few moments.

Comment: Alright, I'll give a link to the paste when it's done and reboot.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Hcwy0i0F | doesn't look like there's any problems, rebooting now!

Comment: Awesome! I will have another edit tomorrow if Hurricane Florence leaves me with any power!

Comment: Good luck with that, man!