# Netgear A7000 worked in 18.10, not 19.04?

Tags: networking, drivers, upgrade, netgear, 19.04

I had my Netgear A7000 working with 18.10 when I followed the directions here:

[Netgear A7000 on Ubuntu 16.04 not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025695/netgear-a7000-on-ubuntu-16-04-not-working)

However, once upgrading to 19.04, the dongle is acting dead.  Works fine when booted back into Windows.

I've tried re-applying the steps in the link above, but the messages I get definitely suggest those drivers are already embedded in the upgraded system.  Not sure how to proceed.  Please advise.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ditto to above , except my system is 18.04.2, worked fine until update in week 3 of April. Adapter works fine on a win10 laptop, possible kernel problem ?? I fixed it by using the following:

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8814au/4.3.21 -–all
```

then repeating the install lines:

```
sudo dkms add ./rtl8814au
sudo dkms build -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21
sudo dkms install -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21
```

Hope this helps.