# Cannot install A7000 USB-WiFi Adapter on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers

As title says, I'm trying to get the A7000 USB WiFi adapter working on a Thinkpad laptop with Ubuntu 18.04.

I followed the instructions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025695/netgear-a7000-on-ubuntu-16-04-not-working) which were to go:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8814au 
sudo dkms build -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21
sudo dkms install -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21
```

Then reboot.  All steps appeared to be completed successfully, such that now when I type the last command, I get the expected message:

```
$ sudo dkms install -m rtl8814au -v 4.3.21
Module rtl8814au/4.3.21 already installed on kernel 5.3.0-42-generic/x86_64
```

But STILL, `iwconfig` does not show the device (just my normal builtin wifi, and `no wireless extensions` for `lo` and `enp0s31f6`), while `lsusb` indicates it's there (`Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0846:9054 NetGear, Inc.`).

Any thoughts, friends?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe 8814au && dmesg | grep -i rtl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8814au': Operation not permitted`

Comment: Or if you meant `sudo modprobe rtl8814au && dmesg | grep -i rtl` it gives you `modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8814au not found in directory /lib/modules/5.3.0-45-generic`

Comment: Above you said you were running kernel version -42 and now it says -45. Please show: `sudo dkms status`

Comment: Hmmm yeah good point it seems to have changed since I made the question... still nothing in iwconfig though. ... `sudo dkms status` gives me 
`rtl8814au, 4.3.21, 5.3.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed`  
`rtl8814au, 4.3.21, 5.3.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed`

Comment: "modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8814au': Operation not permitted" Did you include sudo?

Comment: I did include sudo - turned out I needed to [disable secure boot](https://askubuntu.com/a/1198351/765019) though.  Did that, and now `sudo modprobe 8814au` just hangs, providing no output.  If I run it with `-vvv`, I get: https://pastebin.com/62QyXjnB

Comment: I'm not sure I see anything wrong and therefore fixable in your paste. Are there any other clues here? `dmesg | grep -i -e rtl -e 8814`

Comment: Hmmm nothing intelligable to me: https://pastebin.com/zBdJysLk

Comment: There is quite a bit here. We see the 8814au driver stumbling, throwing errors, crashing and sort of recovering only to start the same process again. You have the latest driver version that I can find, 4.3.21. I am persuaded by some of the clues at the github repository: "forked from tpircher/rtl8814AU" Notice that the repository hasn't been amended in about ten months.

Comment: At the mentioned tpircher repository, the README says: "This repository is no longer maintained. If you are thinking of buying a product with this chip in: don't, unless you are prepared to put a considerable amount of work in yourself. More generally, don't buy any hardware that is not supported by the mainline kernel." In short, I know of no way to make this device and driver combination work properly. Sorry.

Comment: Ah, oh well, some things weren't meant to be.  Thank you for your help along the way.  What I might try as a work-around is the plug it into a Raspberry Pi with an older kernel version and use the Pi's own WiFi as a hotspot.